# Как вывести на печать таблицу со стилями

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Мне нужно распечатать таблицу которая выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при печати это выглядит вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нагуглил вот такой вот код

```
     function printInfo(strId) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(strId);
        var openWindow = window.open('','','left=50,top=50,width=800,height=640,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
        var prtCss = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for("static", filename="index_style.css")}}" type="text/css" media="all">';
        openWindow.document.write(prtCss);
        openWindow.document.write(ele.outerHTML);
        openWindow.document.close();
        openWindow.focus();
        openWindow.print();
        openWindow.close();
    }
```

На печать я отправляю див t1. Пример таблицы ниже (таблица не заполнена, но результат тот же, нет стилей)

```
<div id="t1" class="t1">
            <table id="schedule">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;">
                        ПН
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;">
                        ВТ
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;">
                        СР
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;">
                        ЧТ
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;">
                        ПТ
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                {%for row in range(4) %}
                {% for col in range(5) %}

                <td class="td" >
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                        <td id="{{(col+1)|string + (row+1)|string}}_up">&emsp;&emsp;<br>&emsp;&emsp;<br>&emsp;&emsp;<br>&emsp;&emsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td id="{{(col+1)|string + (row+1)|string}}_down"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                {% endfor %}
                <tr></tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Вам надо указать правильный путь у вашему css файлу. Предпологаю, что вот этот путь не правильный `{{ url_for("static", filename="index_style.css")}}`

Comment: Там надо правильно стили прописывать  [Тут можно прочитать][1] и ещё [тут][2] 


  [1]: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/317776/
  [2]: https://habr.com/ru/post/160997/

Comment: Правильно будет использовать CSS. @media print

Comment: Я пробовал media=print. А выглядит это таким образом потому что фласк, это основной файл со стилями и на самой странице он работает нормально